# Which is the main clause and why - "I do not want to..." or "my eyes started to..."?

Tags: clauses, exam-questions

Which is the main clause and why? "I do not want to help my mom in the kitchen anymore"  or " my eyes started to cry" (the punctuation is just like the original)

Since I am not convinced about an answer I received previously, and did not want to continue arguing, I think the answer to this question might convince me (the following appears in a test).

> "I do not want to help my mom in the kitchen anymore, this morning while_________ onions, my eyes started to cry."
>   a. peeling
>   b. I was peeling
>   c. peel
>   d. was peeling

Comment: That's not a single sentence...  That's two sentences that someone has used a comma between instead of using a period.

Comment: Thank   you, Catija!    I had thought about that mistake, too. Now, everything is clearer!

Comment: Note that you could use a colon or semicolon instead of a comma, and that would make it grammatically correct.

Comment: Thanks, Era. I only knew about a possible period or semi colon.

Comment: "My eyes started to cry" seems an odd way of phrasing it. I would say either "my eyes started to water" or "I started to cry".

Answer (score 1):

1: There are two independent clauses and one dependent clause in your sentence. You have to use either semicolon or end period, if you are using two independent clauses.

2: Right answer is "I was peeling"

> I do not want to help my mom in the kitchen anymore; this morning while **I was peeling** onions, my eyes started to cry.

Comment: Is there any reason why "peeling" can't be the right answer?

Comment: @Rathony - because that would mean that it was the eyes doing the peeling...

Comment: Can human's eyes peel onions?

Comment: @Rathony - Of course not, but grammatically that is what it would mean. All four answers result in a sentence that is understandable, but this *is* a grammar question. You could say "...while peeling onions, I found my eyes started to..."

Comment: Grammatically, there are many participial clauses where subjects are omitted when they are contextually obvious or could be inferred/identified without looking at the subject of the main clause. I think it is better to explain this to learners and I would not use the construction "I found my eyes started to..."

Comment: @Rathony It is a type of **dangling modifier**; check this [website](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/1/)  for additional information